# Fastest way to match substring from large dict

Tags: python, algorithm, search, text, substring

I have some (usually < 300 symbols length) string like 'aabbccdcabcbbacdaaa'.

There is python dictionary where keys are strings in similar format, e.g. 'bcccd', key length varies from 10 to 100 symbols. The dictionary has **half a million** items.

I need to match my initial string with dictionary's value or find out that there are no proper values in dictionary. Matching condition: dictionary key should be somewhere within string (strict matching).

What is the best way, in terms of computational speed, to do it?
I feel there should be some tricky way to hash my initial string and dictionary keys as to apply some clever ways of substring search (like Rabin-Karp or Knuth-Morris-Pratt). Or suffix tree-like structure could be a good solution?

Comment: Wouldn't a trie be enough in this case?

Comment: The `in` operator in Python has strict matching, so you could use it. It's also a built-in, so it's reasonably fast.

Comment: The dictionary does not play a role here, you basically got a list of strings (your keys) and the longer string. [Aho-Corasick](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aho%E2%80%93Corasick_algorithm) would be quite a good fit here - especially if your dictionary is more or less stable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
def search(string, dict_search):
    # If those 2 lines are too expensive, calculate them and pass as arguments
    max_key = max(len(x) for x in dict_search)
    min_key = min(len(x) for x in dict_search)

    return set(
        string[x:x+i] 
        for i in range(min_key, max_key+1)
        for x in range(len(string)-i+1)
        if string[x:x+i] in dict_search
    )
```

Running:

```
>>> search('aabbccdcabcbbacdaaa', {'aaa', 'acd', 'adb', 'bccd', 'cbbb', 'abc'})
{'aaa', 'abc', 'acd', 'bccd'}
```

Comment: Your function should have found `'aaa'` so it may be missing the last character of the search string.

Comment: @AustinKootz Thanks. It was missing a `+1` on the second for loop

Answer (score 5):

Just found a reasonable implementation of Aho-Corasick for Python - [pyahocorasick](https://pypi.org/project/pyahocorasick/). Taking from the example at the end of the page:

```
import ahocorasick
A = ahocorasick.Automaton()

for k, v in your_big_dict.iteritems():
    A.add_word(k, v)

A.make_automaton()
for item in A.iter(your_long_string):
    print(item)
```

Comment: Is there a memberfunction to report the number of states after constructing the automaton. I'm very curious about the OP's 500K (small) patterns from a small (4?) alphabet ...

Comment: `.dump()` and `.get_stats()` seem to provide some info. But you have to ask the OP on the character of his data;)

Comment: Thanks a lot! +1 to all of you fellows, but JBernardo's solution suits me better for technical reasons.

Comment: It is hard to beat ahocorasick on this problem. It would be my choice too :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following format:

```
for key in your_dictionary:
    if key in your_string:
        print(key+' is in both your string and the dictionary. It has the value '+str(your_dictionary[key]))
```

If you want this changed in any way, let me know in the comments, I'll be happy to update.

Comment: There are two problems with this approach: 1) The string is much smaller than the dict, so traversing the dict to test should be more expensive than finding the pieces of the string to search. 2) String seach is `O(n)` while dict seach is `O(1)` on average case.

Comment: Also: `for key in your_dictionary:` There is no value there